# REQUEST link missing in openerp 6.1 web client

Tags: odoo

I am not seeing the "REQUEST" link on top right corner of the openerp web client.
I am using OpenERP 6.1.1 .

Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenERP have removed the 'REQUEST' link from openerp v6.1.1 web client. Still the res.request model exists in openerp v6.1.1, I think they are trying to remove the res.request model. Try to use email_template, so that whenever a notification comes, send a mail to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Atom you are right the request object still exists but as part if USB improvement it has been dropped from the top right corner.But yes the object is still all accessible through Menu:

`Settings > Customization >Low Level Object > Requests > Requests`

With right access right you can show this menu where you like. cause security is till same as it was in 6.0.X.

Regards